# How do you query the friend whose posts you like?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm having a lot of trouble with this. I'm trying to find which friends I'm most connected to so what I have been doing is selecting the userId from from a table that I can match the object Id with (so this only works for videos, notes, links, photos, or albums) and then saying that object id (the name is different for each type- status_id, link_id etc) has to match select object_id from like where user_id=me() (since i only care about the things I like) and object_type="whatever i'm looking for."`

But I can't do this with the stream because I can't grab the post_id from likes. And even if I could grab the post_ids from the stream there is no good way of then getting the userId, which is all I care about. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select like_info, uid from status where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me())

Well thanks to a friend at Facebook I figured this out. You have can select your friends statuses that you liked by filtering who posted them to your friends and then selecting the uid (so you can know the person's status that you liked) and like_info. In like_info there is a field user_likes which is a boolean if you the user liked it or not.